# I'm trying to create a query using the SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create a query using the SQL SELECT statement but I keep getting a error with my code
This is my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblRegistration
WHERE (tblRegistration.InstanceID IN (
    SELECT InstanceID FROM tblRegistration
    SELECT tblCourse.InstanceID, tblCourse.HoursPerWeek
    FROM tblCourse
    WHERE (((tblCourse.HoursPerWeek)=40));
```

[image: The error message I keep getting]

[image: Question]

Comment: This looks like a bracketing issue. There’s a missing bracket here ⇢ `FROM tblRegistration SELECT` and too many here ⇢ `WHERE (((tblCourse.HoursPerWeek)` 

Comment: Suggest you use query designer to build query that references query objects then switch to SQLView and copy/paste SQL statements to replace object references. Have to enclose the subquery statement in parentheses. Your nested queries make no sense. Edit your question to provide sample data as text tables.

Answer (score 1):

Access throws in far more parentheses in WHERE clause than are needed. Simplify by removing most of them then test. Access will eventually throw them back in if you switch builder between datasheet and design view and save the object. Always make sure brackets, parens, quote marks, and apostrophes are evenly paired.

Also have too many SELECT clauses.

Subquery for IN() must return only one field.

Consider:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblRegistration
WHERE tblRegistration.InstanceID IN (
    SELECT tblCourse.InstanceID
    FROM tblCourse
    WHERE tblCourse.HoursPerWeek=40);
```

If you don't want to remove field from subquery, try:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblRegistration
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT tblCourse.InstanceID, tblCourse.HoursPerWeek
    FROM tblCourse
    WHERE tblCourse.HoursPerWeek=40);
```